# I'm in static resources, and I made a new view -- now I can't see all

Tags: view

I went to static resources and, by default, it shows all resources. I wanted to be able to see only specific ones easily, so I named them icon_'something' and created a new view for resources that have that prefix.

That works, but I do not have a view all option anymore, just the "Icons" view I made. How do I view all of them now?

Comment: The answers provided here also apply to other types of Setup resources that exhibit this behavior, like Apex Classes, Triggers, and so on. Once you create at least one list view, the All option disappears, and you have to create a new All list view if you want it back.

Comment: I thought I tried this, but I think I was editing Icon instead. Ooops. Worked, of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another custom `List View` and name it "All". Don't include any criteria.

Creating a custom `List View` on any object removes the default "All" view but you can easily add it back in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your you new and Create another view by removing your _something condition and name it All Resource and click save as as show below

[image]